# Want To change the name of menu item dynamically in Login Or LogOff of Same Item

Tags: android, android-layout

I Want To Change the name of Item i.e Login Or Logoff When The User Is Login It Show Logoff Or When User Is Logoff It Show Login Only One Button but Iit Does Not Set the Title Of The item

Actually I Want To Use Only One Button For Login Or Logout But Name Is Changed Please help me .thanking you in Advance

```
      private void showPopup() {
    PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(this, toolbar);
    menu.inflate(R.menu.menu_main);
    menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.action_home:
                    Intent profile_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this ,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(profile_intent);
                    return true ;

                case R.id.action_logoff:
                    LoginResponseModel loginData2 = PrefManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getLoginData();
                    if(loginData2 != null) {
                        PrefManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).putString(PrefConstants.LOGIN_RESPONSE, "");
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        item.setTitle("Log Off");
                        return true ;
                    }else{
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        item.setTitle("Log In");
                        return true ;
                    }

        }
    });
    MenuPopupHelper menuHelper = new MenuPopupHelper(this, (MenuBuilder) menu.getMenu(), toolbar);
    menuHelper.setForceShowIcon(true);
    menuHelper.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    menuHelper.show();
}
```

Now i Want to do When The Passenger Is Login In then the item 
    Name Show Login Otherwise Logoff

```
         @Override
            public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
           super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
     MenuItem someMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_logoff);
//        MenuItem someMenuItem1 = menu.findItem(R.id.action_logout);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Loginhhh");
    LoginResponseModel loginData2 = PrefManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getLoginData();
    if (loginData2 != null) {
        someMenuItem.setTitle(s);
    }else {
        someMenuItem.setTitle(s);

    }
    return true;
}
```

my Xml Code Is

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="io.rebu.passenger.activity.MainActivity">
       <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logoff"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Log In"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
 </menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `invalidateOptionsMenu()` at end of you button click event

```
case R.id.action_logoff:
                    LoginResponseModel loginData2 = PrefManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getLoginData();
                    if(loginData2 != null) {
                        PrefManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).putString(PrefConstants.LOGIN_RESPONSE, "");
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        item.setTitle("Log Off");

                    }else{
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        item.setTitle("Log In");

                    }
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); //<-- Add this line
                    return true ;
```